# php ajax live update vs bulk update

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server

While developing student mark entry system, suppose a page has 100-200 students (can reach 1000) and each student has 5-6 subject, so at least 500/600 input value to update.

Now I am in dilemma, which method to choose to update - **live update** vs **bulk update**

Creating one update button and store tables all `tr` value in one large `array` and send through `JavaScript ajax` ? By doing bulk update, it will be less ajax calls.

Or through **live update**, calls `ajax` to **each** input value change and update in MySQL row by row.

I prefer live update. Because it will send and updates only specific row that we need. But we have also option `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL side in bulk update.

Actually, live update would do lot of ajax calls. Does it affect to server, load or hang ?

Comment: Are you updating every student in every subject every time you load the page(log in)? If you are only updating a half dozen or so entries when you look at the data, just set up a database update on "blur" or "change" of a select or checkbox. You don't need to resubmit all the information, just your changes. You could even make each row its own mini form, so you can submit changes just for that row. Also, if you are printing all the data to your screen you may lag or even crash your system.

Comment: @Vbudo, It doesn't update automatically with loading page. Previously I had create update button to update, after the triggering button only process start. Now I am planning to call ajax to each changes. I mean through `onchange` event. By doing so, it ajax would be called to each changes or entry. So want to know does `live update` affects to the server side